# Bootstrap 4 Nav bar collapsing is not happening when running from local

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4, togglebutton

I am trying to make a Collapsible Nav Bar in Bootstrap 4.0.0. I have downloaded and added Bootstrap.min.css, bootstrap.min.js and jquery(3.2.1) also.

when i am running this in browser, collapsing functionality is not happening. i.e., when I reduce the browser size, at the right side of the page one toggle icon is coming. But when I am clicking on that, collapsing is not happening.

Kindly help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure your import Jquery.js before bootstrap.min.js for this to work before `</body>`
2. Open browser console to see if there are any errors there, maybe your js files are not found due to the wrong path.

Comment: Thanks Sayd Fuad, you make my day. The mistake which I did is I have placed my imported jqueries after bootstrap.min.js.

Comment: can you suggest me what are the required .js files for Bootstrap4.0.0

Comment: Most of the time bootstrap.min.css ,bootstrap.min.js and Jquery will do.

Answer (score 0):

First of all please follow **SO** rules of asking questions and attach to your answer a minimal code or screenshots of anything helps us to debug and fix your issue.

The common cause for this issue is that you need to include `popper.js` file in your source code or you have your files included in the wrong order.

See you console in the developer tools to know better what is happening.

Comment: Thanks Moayad, you make my day. The mistake which I did is I have placed my imported jqueries after bootstrap.min.js. can you suggest me what are the required .js files for Bootstrap4.0.0